# Why are LINQ operators defined as extension methods on IEnumerable interface and are not part of the interface itself? C#

Tags: c#, linq, oop, interface, extension-methods

So extension methods are used to add functionality to a class without a need to modify it's current code. I read that LINQ operators are defined that way.

My question is, when we know we want LINQ operators with every class that implements IEnumerable, why aren't LINQ operators defined directly in IEnumerable interface? Why use extension methods?

Thank you.

Comment: Because LINQ was designed this way. Because one doesn't necessary need LINQ in an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Linq methods work on arrays or lists.  Singletons will not work.  Standard objects like Arrays or Lists have IEnumerable() build in.  So if you create a class and then add to a List<MyClass> then you can use linq methods.

Comment: Also, `IEnumerable` is an interface, so you can't define them in the IEnumerable.

Comment: Prior to C# 8 one can't implement concrete method in interfaces. users of `IEnumerable` should implement the whole LINQ features ?

Comment: @Cid Wow, didn't realize C# 8 brings default implementations in interfaces. That sounds really... dumb

Comment: One thing I didn't think before posting the question was that putting them in interface would make all it's users to provide the implementation. Also IEnumerable's main responsibility is not to provide linq operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is three-fold:

1. Changing the IEnumerable's interface is a breaking change for existing consumers. Since .NET 3.5 (When LINQ was introduced) wasn't the only version of .NET in production (at the time there .NET 2.0 and .NET 1.1), Microsoft's .NET team had to be particularly careful with changes.
2. One fundamental part in architecting software is understanding the Object SOLID design principle ["the Open-Closed" principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) (the "O" in SOLID). Also known as [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). That is, when you are building software, prefer to have lego pieces that can work together to compose the lego result you want, not have a lego brick have all of that functionality built in to its inheritance chain.  Not every lego brick needs the functionality of a lego wheel, but if you use inheritance every lego brick will have access to that functionality -- probably not what you want.

   By using composition and setting up the new extension method syntax; Microsoft could add on functionality to the Enumerable interface without worrying about existing consumers of IEnumerable, and none of those implementations would have to implement the entire set of LINQ operators, which they would have to do if it was baked in to the IEnumerable interface.
3. `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` were named simply: Provide an interface for a common way of iterating over a collection. That way everyone from hither to yon that needs to iterate over a collection can use this interface.  If they start adding things to that interface that don't have to do with enumeration, the consumers will start to get confused.  "What is this thing for again?"

   Another principle in software development is the Single Responsibility Principle (The S in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)), and when you have a class or interface that is responsible for two or things, it's time to revisit why that interface exists.

Comment: And the O of SOLID is [Open-Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)

Comment: 4. It would require that all implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` implement the full set of LINQ operations. With extension methods they get this for free.

Comment: @Cid Thank you! The initial draft had Composition over Inheritance as a SOLID Principle but I couldn't remember off hand which part of SOLID it was. Your comment jogged my memory. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That' a good point that I alluded to but did not explicitly point out; I'll do that.